# Describe the family of analytic functions with the following properties:

Tags: complex-analysis

Find the family of all functions $f$ analytic in $\mathbb{D}$ (the open unit disk) and continuous on $\overline{\mathbb{D}}$ such that $|f(z)|=e^{\text{Re}(z)}$ for all $z\in\mathbb{D}$.

My intuition tells me that the family of functions is $\mathcal{F}=\{f_\alpha(z)=e^{z+i\alpha}|\alpha\in\mathbb{R}\}$. I know that this satisfies all the requirements, but I have no idea how to show that it is an exhaustive list (which I'm guessing is supposed to be the "meat and potatoes" of this problem). I can't think of any other mapping that will turn vertical lines and/or line segments into concentric circles/portions of said circles.

Any insight would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

**Hint** If $g(z) =\frac{f(z)}{e^z}$, then $|g(z)| =1$ on $\overline{\mathbb{D}}$.

Deduce that $g(z)$ is constant on $\overline{\mathbb{D}}$. The constant then $C$ must have $|C|=1$, and writing it in exponential form gives what you want.